# How to create summary of multiple columns from multiple pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to check any loss of data in categorical columns (such as data for an entire category) after data cleansing. i have 2 series that contains unique values of each categorical column in the dataframes.

Before Data Cleansing

- dataframe1.nunique()

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Column 1 | 10 |
| Column 2 | 20 |

After Data Cleansing

- dataframe2.nunique()

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Column 1 | 10 |
| Column 2 | 15 |

Any idea how to get a table in the following format for better presentation ? Both dataframe has same columns, but not same row count.

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Column 1 | 10 | 10 |
| Column 2 | 20 | 15 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: use `df1.merge(df2,on='Column Name',suffixes=('_before','_after'))`

Comment: ok..i have updated my question, dataframe2.nunique() gives us series, where first column contains column names and second column contains unique values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `concat()` method:

```
df=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
df.columns=['Unique Value Count_before','Unique Value Count_after']
```

**OR**

via `to_frame()` and `merge()` method

```
df=df1.to_frame().merge(df2.to_frame(),on='Column Name',suffixes=('_before','_after'))
```

Output:

```
Column Name Unique Value Count_Before   Unique Value Count_After
Column 1    10                          10
Column 2    20                          15
```